# Third party replacement component for craxdrt to view Crystal Report file

Tags: crystal-reports, report

We have a set of Crystal Reports `*.rpt` files which is used by our VB6 application to display the reports in Crystal Report viewer or Microsoft Word. To accomplish this our VB6 application use `craxdrt.dll` and `crviewer.dll` 
 (Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer Run Time Library & Micorsoft Word and Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer Library respectively).

Due to some issues we would like to remove our application dependencies on `craxdrt.dll` and `crviewer.dll`. Since we have lots of `.rpt` files we are looking for a component which can replace `craxdrt.dll` and `rviewer.dll` and can work with the existing .rpt files.

Comment: You need to pose a question... you have only submitted a scenario...

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- [Crystal Reports Viewer](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalviewer/index.epx?URL_ID=crcom)
- decouple reporting from your application and use [Crystal Reports Server](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/index.epx?URL_ID=crcom)
- migrate your application to .Net and use [Crystal Reports for
  Visual Studio .NET](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports-visualstudio/index.epx?URL_ID=crcom)